# netstat how to exclude localhost from the result when using grep

Tags: centos, grep, netstat

When I run this command in my terminal:

```
netstat -an | egrep ":80|:443" | sort
```

I got this following output:

```
tcp        0      0 172.104.10.125:48310    172.104.10.125:8081     TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 172.104.10.125:48316    172.104.10.125:8081     TIME_WAIT    
tcp        0      0 172.104.10.125:48428    172.104.10.125:8081     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.104.10.125:80       0.0.0.0               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 172.104.10.125:80       5.111.110.185:23784     SYN_RECV   
tcp        0      0 172.104.10.125:80       89.109.64.166:42690     TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 ::1:443                 ::                    LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 172.104.10.125:443      60.51.33.253:65270      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.104.10.125:443      66.249.79.94:49202      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 172.104.10.125:8080     172.104.10.125:39668    TIME_WAIT
```

The 172.104.10.125 is my IP address, how do I exclude the above result that have '172.104.10.125', '0.0.0.0' and '::' on the 5th column ? Because those are trusted localhost IP and protocol.

If I use this:

```
egrep -v "172.104.10.125|::|0.0.0.0"
```

it will exclude everything not on the 5th column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use awk

```
awk '$5 !~ "^(172\.104\.10\.125:[0-9]+|0\.0\.0\.0|::)$"'
```

but grep can do it

```
grep -Ev '^([^ ]+ +){4}(172\.104\.10\.125:[0-9]+|0\.0\.0\.0|::)'
```

Comment: Wow I didn't know that we can specify {4} using grep! Both are working. Thank you so much!

Comment: I got a warning when using awk: ---> awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'

Comment: strange, tested it before posting.

Comment: '{4}'  probably not without the "-E"